# What file types does header("Content-Encoding: gzip") support?

Tags: php

I'm using this snippet:

```
// ... snip

header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
include some_file;

// ... snip
```

to serve zipped content.

What types of encoding can I serve this way.  i.e what can i put in for some_file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This just tells the receiver that the sender compressed the payload using gzip compression algorithm and it will need to be decompressed when received. For example a server may compress a very large page and send it to the client, the client will need to decompress it before it can be processed further.

As @Evert points out, the client must be able to accept gzipped data.

This does not have anything to do with downloading gzip archives so file type is irrelevant.

If you want to specify the type of file being downloaded, this is done with the `Content-Type` header. For example:

```
header("Content-Type: application/gzip"); // for GZIP archive files
header("Content-Type: application/zip"); // for ZIP archive files
```

Or more generically:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); // for arbitrary binary data
```

Answer (score 4):

Everything, as long as it's gzipped. But you should only serve files like that if the client sends: `Accept-Encoding: gzip`

Comment: I was under the impression that most ( if not all ) modern browsers (clients) accept this?

Comment: Pretty much all browsers will, yea. It's still smart to be robust and compliant with HTTP. That means only sending back gzipped data when the client requested it.

Comment: ...how would I know if the client requested it, from the server side, is there a PHP parameter I can check?

Comment: yea, it's in `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']`. Anyway, I think your question is answered. You can easily find more information by googling the subject